# RAM choice when CPU supports max. 1333MHZ - 16GB in 1333Mhz or 1600Mhz? Same price level

Tags: memory, compatibility, ddr3

I’ve read that both the processor and motherboard determine the max. speed of RAM for your system.

System: Asus K53SV-SX146V

Processor:  i5-2410M
 - supports RAM up to 2x 8GB 1333mhz

Motherboard:    Intel Mobile HM65 Chipset
 - supports RAM speed up to 1600mhz

I want to upgrade my RAM from 4GB to 16GB (reason; I want to be able to run VMs with no problems and more). 1333Mhz is fast enough because that’s the max. supported amount of mhz my processor supports. However, buying 16gigs in 1600Mhz is as cheap nowadays as its counterpart in the 1333Mhz version. 16GB in 1600Mhz is obviously also more of a future kit, and I can get the 16GB 1600mhz as a kit instead of 2 separate sticks.

This raises a question: is the i5-2410m compatible with 1600Mhz RAM? I’ve read somewhere that the processor will set the speed of the RAM to 1333Mhz. That’s fine to me. Is this true? And if so; will the 1333Mhz RAM in some way noticably outperform the 1600Mhz RAM because the processor doesn’t have to interfere with it’s native settings to run it?

I can buy (selection based upon cheapest €/GB):

Option a.   a kit of:
 - 2x8GB 
 - 1600mhz
 - CL10
 - 1.5v

- total: €136.80

Option b.   2 seperate sticks (not a kit) of:
 - 8GB 
 - 1333mhz 
 - CL9 
 - 1.35v

- total: €135.15

Where lies the value in your opinion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, you can use 1600 MHz RAM, but if your chipset cannot support it, it will run at 1333 MHz. It will make no difference whatsoever with regard to your "because the processor doesn’t have to interfere with it’s native settings to run it?" question. Also please note that shopping recommendations are off-topic on SuperUser. You might want to edit your question!

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've edited the question, it's more of an economist perspective and not doesn't refer to specific products now.

Comment: You mean "forwards compatible" and not backwards?

Comment: @tumchaaditya - Yes you're right. I just removed the word for readibility.

Comment: Why look forward with DDR3 when in less than 24 months all chipsets sold will be DDR4; pointless to future proof old technology; besides the frequency will result in literally no improvement that you will notice; so the choice should be based on price alone

Answer (score 0):

With regard to the two options you mention, an **important thing** to note is:

Voltage

You need to make absolutely sure whether or not your PC / motherboard / chipset supports 1.5V and/or 1.35V memory.

From [this site](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/K53SV/specifications/) it would seem that the maximum memory size for your system is 8GB, so be sure that your system supports 16GB before upgrading. A quick search on [Kingstons memory guide](http://www.kingston.com/en/memory/search/Default.aspx?DeviceType=3&Mfr=ASU&Line=K53%20Notebook&Model=72131&Description=Kingston_ValueRam_Memory_System_Specific_Memory_for_ASUS/ASmobile_K53_Notebook_K53SV) suggests you should be able to use up to 8 GB memory with a voltage of 1.5V

I would be sure to double check compatibility, as I am fearful none of the options you mention would work in your PC.

**Guaranteed to work is:** 2x 4GB Module - DDR3, 1333MHz, CL9, 1.5V, SODIMM, 204-pin

Hope this helps answer your question.

Comment: I know what's guaranteed to work, but thanks for your answer. The note on 1.35v vs 1.5v RAM compatibility is something to check though :)